# How to insert into one column in table using select in phpmyadmin

Tags: phpmyadmin

I have two table like below :

Users_Data:

```
Listing_id | Country | Keywords
1          | Belgium | 
2          | USA     | 
3          | Brazil  |
```

Temp Table:

```
Listing_id | Keywords
1          | iqmal
2          | aiman
3          | afiq
```

I want to insert keywords from Temp Table into keywords Users_Data table.
Please help me.

Comment: That's not insert That's update

Comment: can i use insert? update will take much time. I have milion data to edit.

Comment: `update Users_Data  
join Temp 
on Temp.Listing_id =Users_Data.Listing_id 
set Users_Data.keywords=Temp.keywords; `

Comment: can you take look on my answer for insert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simple update the data  using `join`

```
update Users_Data  
join Temp 
on Temp.Listing_id =Users_Data.Listing_id 
set Users_Data.keywords=Temp.keywords;
```

**For Insert Follow these steps**

**1st :** you can create table with same structure

```
 create table new_table like Users_Data
```

**2nd :**  simple select the data from both table and insert like below

```
insert into new_table select Users_Data.Listing_id,Users_Data.Country,Temp.keywords  
join Temp 
on Temp.Listing_id =Users_Data.Listing_id
```

Comment: Glad to help you  :) .and take care about my comments .

Answer (score 0):

If it is MySQL, try with inner join :

```
update Users_Data u
inner join Temp t on
    u.Listing_id = t.Listing_id
set u.Keywords = t.Keywords
```